# What is an id<> variable, and does it auto initialize?

Tags: objective-c, variables, delegates, initialization

I'm currently working with an API (Insiteo) that requires me to use an `id<ISPInitListener>`. It tells me to use it in the initialisation function:

```
id<ISPCancelable> initTask = [[ISInitProvider instance] startAPIWithServerType:ISEServerTypeProd andSiteId:SITE_ID andLanguage:LANGUAGE andInitListener:aListener];
```

Where 'aListener' is the `id<ISPInitListener>`. I can see that the `ISPInitListener` is an `NSObject` but don't actually know the best way to initialise / use it in this function? Can anyone explain how these sort of objects work?

I currently have `ISPInitListener` added here `@interface LONetworkLocationManager () <UITextViewDelegate, UIAlertViewDelegate, ISPInitListener>` but the delegate functions related to the ISP never get called.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`id` is a special type that means "any object type" in Objective-C.

Angular brackets are used to indicate protocol conformance.

Putting the two together, `id<ISPInitListener>` means "any object conforming to the `ISPInitListener` protocol".

This is typically used for indicating the type of a delegate object, in which you don't care about the specific type of an object, but only about the conformance to the protocol that defines the specific delegate, in this case `ISPInitListener`.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think I found the answer to this at http://unixjunkie.blogspot.co.uk/2008/03/id-vs-nsobject-vs-id.html:

> Declaring an object as id tells the compiler that you don't care what type the object is, but you do care that it conforms to the specified NSObject protocol**. The compiler will ensure that all objects you assign to that pointer conform to the required protocol. A pointer typed like this can safely hold any NSObject (because NSObject conforms to the NSObject protocol), but it could also hold any NSProxy, because NSProxy also conforms to the NSObject protocol. In english, the declaration id foo3; says "foo3 is a pointer to an object of any type that behaves like an NSObject". This is very powerful, convenient, and expressive. In reality, we often don't care what type an object is, we just care that it responds to the messages that we want to send it (e.g., retain, release).